# Multiple instances of application

Tags: tomcat, deployment

Is it possible to create multiple instances of your application and run them on the same server and same tomcat container. How ?

Answer (score 1):

Can you just create a new descriptor file for each? That is, multiple descriptor files in <tomcat_home>/conf/Catalina/localhost. Each one gets a different name (app1.xml, app2.xml) so they're deployed at /app1, /app2, etc, but you reference the same .war.

app1.xml:

```
<Context path="/app1" docBase="/path/to/your.war" reloadable="false"/>
```

app2.xml:

```
<Context path="/app2" docBase="/path/to/your.war" reloadable="false"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should be able to deploy the same application as multiple instances on one tomcat server as long as the context roots are different.

If you are using tomcat's auto-deploy mechanism, you simply have to name your war as the context root you would like it to be deployed at.

For instance name your wars `myapp1.war` and `myapp2.war`. These will deploy to `mysite.com/myapp1` and `mysite.com/myapp2` respectively.

Comment: So does tomcat operate the two instances under two different threads ?

Comment: It is my understanding that each request is a different thread (for each app) from a global thread pool.  Someone please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I've problems with two wars...one works and another one gives me an error 500 java.lang.IllegalStateException...do you know why?